# Android : webview android page not available

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to use WebView but it doesn't work even if i added INTERNET permission on the manifest.xml under the manifest tag

PS: it works on Android emulator but not on my real device :/

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Main activity

```
WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webViewJeu);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("https://www.destinationcocktails.fr/");
view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

XML layout

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewJeu"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tr this:

```
WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webViewJeu);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
view.loadUrl("https://www.destinationcocktails.fr/");
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
   newsDisplayWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.news_web_view);
   newsDisplayWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   newsDisplayWebView.setWebViewClient(new NewsClient());
   newsDisplayWebView.loadUrl("https://sportfirst.sportscotland.org.uk/");
```

and newCliend

```
private class NewsClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Utils.hideProgressbar();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry....that was a helper class in my project you can delete that line because you are not showing any progressbar....... and you can accept the answer if it worked